# Should I continue with mathematics after two-year break?

Tags: graduate-school, mathematics

I would appreciate some advice on my situation if anyone has experienced something similar.

I started my undergraduate degree in mathematics, really doing well and having fun (graduated with distinction in 2020 and was teaching classes). Afterwards I decided to finish my economics degree, which I had taken up parallely. I was much more passionate about math, but thought finishing the degree would be a good idea. Somehow I totally oversaw that I would lose my mathematical ability by taking a break from math.

I finished the economics degree early this year and got admitted into a high-profile postgraduate course in mathematics. Since the start in October I have been struggling, because I am not used to doing problem sheets anymore and do not remember the basic material as well as I used to.

Looking back now I feel I was much better three years ago and have wasted this opportunity. I feel like I would have to go through my whole undergrad again to get back to the level I was at after my math degree… is there any advice on what I should do? Drop out of the degree or maths completely or go back to the basics and work through everything again?

This is really frustrating so I would appreciate some advice.

Comment: Seems like a decision only you can make (perhaps in consultation with your teachers); there is no general answer. How dire is your performance in your postgraduate course? What are your long-term goals?

Comment: Talk to your graduate advisor and see what they suggest. One option could be to retake some undergraduate classes (I know that this is done in some places).

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is "loss of mathematical ability"? There can be quite some gap between undergraduiate and postgraduate programs, regarding level and teaching style. When I did maths, long ago, we were told that learning frustration tolerance is part of it. We had very sophisticated problem sheets that were meant to challenge everyone, but I have seen much easier ones in some UG programs. One option is of course to take the challenge and fight your way through it...

Comment: Are you sure you have to "go back to the basics and work through everything again"? Maybe you can be more selective and lighten the revision task a bit? It is hard to imagine you have forgotten *everything*. Maybe if you start getting into it again, some more stuff comes back automatically.